# How to make a native win32 window dock in a winforms parent?

Tags: winforms, controls, winapi

I would like to take an existing window (I know its window handle, it is not a winforms control), place it into a winforms container and also make it dock with something similar to DockStyle.Fill.

Now, I am able to reparent the window, but I cannot figure out the docking part. I can wrap the child window in a NativeWindow, but NativeWindow is not a WinForms Control class and as such does not have the Dock property.

Is there a way to wrap a generic window handle in a Control? Or do I absolutely need to track the parent control resize events and alter the child native window size accordingly by myself?

Comment: You can't get to the private parts of Control.  Yes, you absolutely need to.